# How to properly update entities using REST and JPA/Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest, jpa

I have entity Document, which has lots of columns, one-to-one, one-to-many and many-to-many mappings to some other entities.

Example:

```
Document:
  id,
  title,
  body,
  authors,
  viewers,
  ...
```

Using REST, I want to update some particular document, controller receives serialized Document object, calling EntityManager's merge method persists null results to the database if controller received for instance only body   , then I want the body to be updated only, but merge deletes records for title, authors and viewers and etc.

I understand that it is a standard behavior of EntityManager, but I am asking what is the most preferred technique to do updates on entities without receiving whole entity from front-end or some other endpoint. Should I load the entity from database using the id I received and set MANUALLY all of the fields and then save to database or should I use another technique.

I don't have any problem with writing manually all of the setters to copy the changes, but entities are really big in size with lots of relations. Asking for best practice in this case.

I know about DTOs but I want alternate approach when using entities for controllers and service methods.

Comment: You can either use  em.merge to update specific fields in a Java entity (this goes via JPA), or you can program an SQL-update statement to do this for you. Basically, JPA is an abstraction layer via entity manager, on top of the SQL-access to the relational database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For entity partial update, you will need to use either criteria api or jpql ... if you are using older versions with no criteria update or old query parser where jpql update is not allowed you will have to read from database first, update then insert again .... you can also make use of `updatable=false` for columns that should be only set on creation (like CREATION_DATE) and there is also a nice feature in hibernate called `@DynamicUpdate` which I haven't tried but looks brilliant ... It only updates the modified field ([check Vlad's post here](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-update-only-a-subset-of-entity-attributes-using-jpa-and-hibernate/)) ... concerning the DTO DP , I you might always need to use if you want to hide / modify some data from the client regardless to the way you store the data ... and it's always a good way to separate concerns (but comes with the mapping headache between domain & DTO objects which is much released thanks to [spring converters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10996461/two-way-converter-in-spring))

Comment: I actually decided to stick with the DTOs with subset of information, but before merging the entity I load it from database and then copy the new values from DTO using simple generic object mapper that I wrote (I think I'll switch to spring converters later if I will need something more complex). Seems like enough for me but not sure...

Answer (score 1):

There are two options one is update query, which works fine but you may feel 
you are loosing some hibernate features and simplicity of the code. Else you can do it in Hibernate way like below

```
   AuditorBean auditorBean = (AuditorBean) session.get(AuditorBean.class, AuditorBean.getId());
    auditorBean.setFirstName("aa");
    auditorBean.setLatName("bb");
    auditorBean.setTrainLevel("ISO");
    auditorBean.setAccessLevel(4);
```

Here you should not call any method like saveOrUpdate() or merge().
object is attached with transaction, so object is flushed and committed at the end of the transaction automatically .